# How To Make Existing .class Files (Java) To Refer To The Updated Property File Value Without Recompiling?

Tags: java, properties, reference, runtime

Now I have this interesting situation. I have a Java project at my disposal but annoyingly the source (.java) files are missing and what I have, are a bunch of .class files. The project also contains a property file (config.property) which is at the root of the project.

Now I have done some changes, basically updated few values of the property file for the existing keys. I haven't introduced any new key though. Just edited the values of few existing keys.

Now since the .class files are already generated, they keep on referring to the old value. Only way I can change that early binding is by regenerating the .class files again. Since I don't have the source with me, I am stuck here.

is there anyway (programatically or otherwise) where I can force these existing .class files to refer the updated property value. What I am looking at for a solution is to write a single utility java file where I will pass these .class files and make them realign themselves with the updated property value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is actually not utilizing the property file but has some hardcoded values inside the classes. If it was using the property file, changing the value should have reflected the change. May be you can decompile the source code (if it is permissible in legal terms and does not have any obfuscation) and update it accordingly to utilize the property file values.